# SqlDataReader issues

Tags: c#, sql-server

The code performs as needed when done like this.

```
SqlDataReader sqlRead = selectCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);

if (sqlRead.Read())
{
    string text = sqlRead["USERNAME"].ToString();

    MessageBox.Show(text);
    connection.Close();
}
```

Whenever written without the if and just the variable declaration like this

```
string text = sqlRead["USERNAME"].ToString();

MessageBox.Show(text);
connection.Close();
```

I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in  System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

Why can't I simply assign the value to the variable? Is it because nothing was actually read into the reader?

Comment: The Read call is mandatory. Otherwise your reader has not read any record. The call positions the reader on the first record (if any) and return true, otherwise return false and you know that there are no more record to read

Comment: `sqlRead.Read()` *fetches* the next record from cursor and return `true` on success, if you don't have any record fetched (data present) you can't read it

Answer (score 2):

That's just how DataReader is written. You must first call the `Read` method before you can get values from it.
See [Retrieving Data Using a DataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader) Microsoft docs:

> You use the **Read** method of the **DataReader** object to obtain a row from the results of the query. You can access each column of the returned row by passing the name or ordinal reference of the column to the **DataReader**.

However, in your case, I would recommend not to use `ExecuteReader()` in the first place. Since you are only interested in one value, you should use `ExecuteScalar` instead, and make sure your SQL statement actually selects the value you want (if, for instance, you are selecting more than one column or more than one row, the `ExecuteScalar` will return the value of the first column in the first row, ignoring all other values that might be returned from the SQL statement).

```
var text = "";
var userName = selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
if(userName != null && userName != DbNull.Value)
{
    text = userName.ToString();
}
```